# Como pasarle un arreglo PHP a una funcion de javascript

Tags: php, javascript, array

Mi codigo javascript es para generar un numero aleattorio y mostrarlo, pero yo quiero que solo lo muestre si no esta ya incluido en el arreglo es el nombre de la varible '**arr**'

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function aleatorio(a,b, arr) {
     var numal = Math.round(Math.random()*(b-a)+parseInt(a));
    if (arr.includes( numa1 ) )
    {
        aleatorio(a,b, arr);
    }
    else
    {
        document.getElementById("sugest").innerHTML=": "+ numal;
    }   
      }
</script>
```

Ahora el arreglo lo tengo en php de una consulta....lo obtengo asi:

```
$query = sprintf("SELECT * FROM db_tabla WHERE id_art = %s",  
GetSQLValueString($colname_Articulo, "int"));
$datos = mysqli_query($connect, $query) or die(mysqli_error($connect));
$row_datos = mysqli_fetch_assoc($datos);
$totalRows_datos = mysqli_num_rows($datos);

$i=1;

do{
$all [$i]= $row_datos['numero'];
$i++;
}while(($row_datos = mysqli_fetch_assoc($datos))&&($i<=$totalRows_datos))

 ?>
```

y llamo a la funcion asi:

```
<button type="button" onClick="aleatorio(1,<?php echo $max ?>,
<?php echo $all ?>);" >Sugerencia   </button>
```

En este caso me dice que:

> notice: array to string conversion

Probe hacer un **json_encode**, pero no se entonces como comprobar dentro de la funcion si el num esta o no en el json...

Comment: <button type="button" class="btn btn-default get" onClick="aleatorio(1,<?php echo $max ?>,<?php echo json_encode($all)?>);" >Sugerencia </button>   la llamo asi, que no salio bien arriba

Comment: o sea primero la llamo sin en joson_encode y me da el error que mencione mas arriba, pero luego la llamo con el json_encode pero no funciona la funcion, no hace nada

Comment: Hola, Maite. ¿Podrías editar tu pregunta, formateando tu código para que se entienda mejor, por favor? (como lo hiciste en el bloque que inicia con `do{`).

Comment: Tu prueba de usar json_encode es probablemente la mejor opción. Comentas que entonces no sabes comprobar si el número está; ¿has probado a hacer un `console.table(arr)` en tu javascript para estudiar la forma del array?

Comment: Primeramente, en el PHP, *mareas* demasiado tus datos para obtener un resultado. Hace falta optimizar ese código, del siguiente modo: **`if ($datos = mysqli_query($connect, $query)) { 
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($datos)) {
        $arrDatos[]=$row;
    } }else{$arrDatos["error"]="Hubo un error en la consulta";} print_r(json_encode($arrDatos);`**

Comment: Podrías hacer un `var_dump($all)` para ver qué tiene? Porque creo saber tu problema pero sin ver los datos de eso no puedo definir una respuesta.

Comment: Otro detallito tal vez a corregir, en la función JS aleatorio(), declaras una variable llamada `numal`, luego preguntas por `numa1` y al final muestras a `numal` en el elemento "sugest". ¿Son `numal` y `numa1` la misma variable?